# Are hierarchical tags useful for applying rules?

Tags: tags, tag-hierarchy

I have some rules that applies to users and I wonder if a solution base on tags could be right. For example I have one user tagged: `Manager` and `Computer scientist`. Because the user is tagged with both, I want to give to the `manager` tag a hierarchical position 2 and `computer scientist` 1, and apply the rules with the higher hierarchical position.

Can it be a good and an easy understandable solution ?

Comment: Take a look at [tag-hierarchy](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-hierarchy) tag for starters, and I'll try to answer when I'm not on an iPad :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually you would sequence the complete set of tags, and the tags earlier in the sequence would have priority over the later tags. It would also be a good idea to maintain that order anytime the tags (all of them or a subset) are displayed so people get an idea of which tags have the higher priority - people would know their first listed tag is their highest priority tag.

Using your example "Computer Scientist" would come before "Manager" in the sequence.

I say "conceptually" sequence them because I'm not sure exactly how you would want to implement this, possibly an array, or a hash, or a JavaScript object.  It can be implemented in many ways as long as you can get the answer to "which of these 2 tags comes first?"

And I ***think*** a better word to describe what you want is "priority" not "hierarchy".

Comment: True that. But you need a system that preserves the tag order, which SE does not. Nice idea!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and it's a good idea to maintain visually the tag order.